# Jquery append div and dynamically set the width

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to append a `div` to a `td` in a `table`. However, as I am appending the div, I want to first take the clientWidth of the td  (to take into account different screensize) and then set the width of the `div` to be that width:

```
var tdWidth = document.getElementById("someId").clientWidth; // ex: 165

td.append("<div Div1 style='margin:auto; width:150px;'><div msg style='color:red'>" + "Text, Text, Text" + "</div></div>");
```

Now I'm trying to apply the 165 value to Div1 (where the width is currently hardcoded to 150px - I'd want to not hardocode it but dynamically set it), but I have no clue how to do this, I tried to do things like:

```
  $('Div1').width(tdWidth);
```

and

```
  var tdWidthPx= tdWidth + 'px';

  $('Div1).css("width",tdWithPx);
```

Ideally I would want to set the width as I append it so that when the text id displayed it is displayed in the correct width.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no HTML attribute called `Div1` or `msg`. Hence, this becomes invalid HTML.

You can append the width like this without hardcoding it initially.

```
var tdWidth = document.getElementById("someId").clientWidth; // ex: 165

td.append("<div style='margin:auto; width:" + tdWidth + "px;'><div  style='color:red'>" + "Text, Text, Text" + "</div></div>");
```

Or else, you can assign an id and later change the width based on id.

```
var tdWidth = document.getElementById("someId").clientWidth; // ex: 165

td.append("<div id='Div1' style='margin:auto; width:150px;'><div style='color:red'>" + "Text, Text, Text" + "</div></div>"); // giving an id to the div element(this id should be unique)
```

The change the width using the id.

```
var tdWidthPx= tdWidth + 'px';

$('#Div1').css("width",tdWithPx);
```

Use the first method if you are not changing the div width dynamically later in the program.